# we see virtual address of a process (in paging system), where does these virtual address exist?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory, memory-segmentation

We see virtual address corresponding to any instruction,so my question is where does these virtual address exist ? If we see disassembly in gdb we saw virtual address where does these address reside ? Please don't say it is only virtual address it have to mapped to a physical address by page table, I know it but where these virtual address that we saw in gdb exist ? In RAM or in Hard disk ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, what's all this about "residing" and "existing" - do you expect there to be a huge list of all possible addresses?

Comment: @harold actually i wants to know about actual position of virtual address, is they reside into disk or RAM ?

Comment: Wherever you put them. They're not that different from other kinds of values. You'll probably have some pointers in registers, RAM, maybe some of that RAM get paged out to disk.. it's a weird question to ask though. It's comparable with "where do array indexes reside".

Comment: @harold array indexs will be going reside into main memory, but we see virtual address corresponding instruction like mov,store. where does these instruction with virtual address are reside, is all of instruction we see in gdb have physical frame ?

Comment: Oh that's what you meant. Your question really is remarkably confusing. Instructions are just data that gets executed. Typical pages containing instructions can be swapped out just as well (there are some pages in the kernel that must be eternally resident), but often they'll be memory mapped pages of an executable file so it would just be dropped as it already exists on disk. That trick is not reserved for instructions. In the end this actually had nothing to do with addresses..

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you, that's what i want to know.

Comment: No problem. my comment should have been more along the lines of "If the instruction pointer is found to be in a page not marked present then it will cause a page fault. The page fault handler will load the page containing the instructions and map it to virtual address space, mark the page present, and then restart at the location the instruction faulted."

Comment: Once restarted the instructions should execute since it is now in memory(present) and mapped to a virtual address. If the instruction itself has a memory reference (accessing a piece of data) and the data isn't present another fault will occur where the page containing the data will be loaded into memory; mapped to a virtual address; marked as present; and then restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An address (or any other numeric value for that matter) can exist in CPU registers, memory and any other storage, including disk. But that probably isn't surprising to you nor is what you're asking about.

If we're talking about 32-bit x86 page translation, then page tables don't contain virtual addresses that undergo translation to physical addresses. Page tables contain only physical addresses, but not virtual. It is not needed to store virtual addresses inside page tables.

Let's simplify things and suppose that the system has only one page table and this page table contains 1024 physical addresses of code/data pages. Where are virtual addresses in here? They are pretty much indices into the page table. If pages are 4KB in size and all addresses are 22-bit, then the 12 low bits of a virtual address specify the location inside a code/data page (0 to 4095) and the 10 top bits of a virtual address select one of the 1024 pages through the page table. When the CPU uses a virtual address to access memory, it breaks the virtual address into an index into the page table and into an offset within the selected page. Then it gets the physical address of the page (from the page table), adds the offset within the page to it and then uses the resultant physical address read or write memory at.

Comment: ok, but lets say at 0x80123456 mov reg1,reg2 is our first instruction in .text section going for execution, is there will be a page fault for 0x80123456 because it is first instruction or physical frame corresponding to 0x80123 virtual page is already loaded into system ? if there will be page page fault then how we see mov reg1,reg2 instruction because there is no physical frame allocated for it,how we see .text section instruction without physically loading it  ?

Comment: @user156991 If you see something in memory (code or data), it means the corresponding virtual addresses were mapped to physical addresses and something was loaded/written to the underlying physical memory at some point. It may be done automatically/on demand by the OS, especially when you memory-map a file (a page fault would tell the OS to map and load). It may be done "manually" by asking the OS (via system calls) to allocate memory (allocate physical memory and map virtual address space to it) and then load file contents into it.

Answer (score 2):

A virtual address does not *exist* in the same way a street address does not exist. Only the house referenced by a street address can exist and in the same way, the storage referenced by a virtual address can (but doesn't have to) exist. What kind of storage that is depends on the system. Typically it's RAM but it can also be ROM, a memory mapped peripheral, open bus (i.e. nothing) or something else.

Comment: @FUZxxi we see instruction in gdb, does all instruction present in physically or we just see it from disk and os get page fault for currently executing instruction (consider case without LOAD,STORE).

Comment: That's implementation defined. The instructions were loaded into RAM at some point, but they might have been swapped out already.

Answer (score 1):

An overall simplification to answer your question relative to the x86 might be this:

If the Instruction Pointer(IP) is found to be associated with a virtual memory address in a page that is marked *not present* it will cause a page fault. The page fault handler will load a free page frame with the code, map it to virtual memory, mark the virtual page *present* and then return back to the virtual memory location with the newly loaded instruction. An attempt to execute the instruction will be made.

If the instruction accesses a memory operand(s) that reference a virtual memory address that is *not present* then they too will cause additional page fault(s). A page fault will occur, the page handler loads the needed data into a free page frame, maps it to a virtual memory, marks the virtual page as *present*, and then returns back to the instruction that caused the fault. At that point the instruction is again retried.

The exact mechanism that an OS uses to maintain page frames; maintain the page tables and directories; decides where/how to load the data/code from are implementation details that will vary. The key thing is that page faults are the primary mechanism to load data/code into virtual memory pages that may have been marked as not present by the OS.